# How does lock on a `static synchronized` block applies?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Consider the following snippet,

```
Class A {

public static synchronized void print() {

   //Print something

}

public static void doSomething() {
    //Do Something
}

}
```

Now is it possible for two threads to access `print()` and `doSomething()` concurrently. Does the lock on `print()` affect `doSomething()` in this case since the lock on `print()` is class level locking. Please clarify me !

Comment: This has nothing to do with static and all to do with two methods being synchronized with the same monitor.

Comment: I have made `synchronised` over only the first method. Then how could my second method locked within the monitor.. Please clarify me..

Comment: Static synchronized method is the same as `synchronized (A.class) {...}`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6

Comment: The synchronization only affects the method(s) that are synchronized.

Comment: If `synchronisation` could affect only the method to which it is applied to then why I couldn't access both method simultaneously (since only one is synchronised and the other one is not). please clarify me...

Comment: Yes, they can be called by different threads because the thread accessing `print` would obtain the monitor for the class object and the `doSomething` method does not require obtaining the monitor.

Comment: @Kamran : So, say a thread T1 is accessing `print` and it holds the lock over the method as it is said as `synchronised` - at the same time another thread T2 could access `doSomething` and it has nothing to do with the monitor which the thread T1 holds. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct.  If, both methods were synchronized, T2 would have to wait until T1 released the monitor when the method `print` returned.

Comment: Super thanks ! @kamran